# deck.js - Is it possible to change the element (body) for the class "deck-container" to another element?

Tags: jquery, javascript, deck.js

Deck.js works fine when I'm using

```
<body class="deck-container"><section>
```

...but it is not working for other elements like divs or <article> etc.  However, on the homepage of Deck.js -- http://imakewebthings.com/deck.js/ -- they are using <article class="deck-container">.

It might be just a small adjustment needed to the JS code.  But I can't find any help in the docs.

It would be very nice if someone could help me out here!

Comment: Can you post your code?  I took a quick look at the deck.js source CSS, and it looks like he's just selecting on the class.  So I would think **article** elements should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The style should be redefined, add this css block and then you can avoid the body class :

```
<head>

<style type="text/css">
.deck-container {
width: auto;
max-width: 864px;
min-height: 560px;
font-size: 16px;
}
</style>

</head>
```